# Insert rows from one table to other table dynamically

Tags: mysql

I  have two tables in my database

```
create table A1 (username varchar(50), Sn int);
create table A2 (username varchar(50), Sn int);
```

i am inserting the data into table A2

```
insert into A2 values("abhi",1);
insert into A2 values("abhi",2);
insert into A2 values("abhi",3);
insert into A2 values("abhi",4);
insert into A2 values("abhi",5);
insert into A2 values("abhi",,6);
```

After that i have to insert the data from table A2 to A1 in such a way that at the first time row insertion will be from 1  to 3 and at the second time  row insertion will be from 4 to 6

Please help me i am new to Mysql

Comment: *"at the first time row insertion will be from 1 to 3 and at the second time row insertion will be from 3 to 6"* -- I don't know what this means.  Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: At the first time the query will run and row from 1 to 3 will insert into A1  and the second time  when query will run then insertion will be from row 4  to 6 into A1

Comment: copy latest 3 rows to A immediately after a row where row_num % 3 == 0 was inserted?

Comment: make up your mind: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
insert into A1 select * from A2 where Sn >= 
(select (case when max(Sn) is null then 0 else max(Sn) end) +1 from A1) 
Limit 3;
```

Comment: I have some doubt will this query help if i will have 1 lakh records in the table. I think while checking max it will slow down the performance . I am using event scheduler for this which will run this query automatically after every 5 minutes

Comment: did you run the query in frond end ah?

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubt will this query help if i will have 1 lakh records in the table. I think while checking max it will slow down the performance . I am using event scheduler for this which will run this query automatically after every 5 minutes